# SELECT COUNT from MS Access to a JTable with DButils

Tags: java, sql, select, count, jtable

I have a JDBC:ODBC connection to a MS Access Database which populates a JTable with DButils. My basic SQL queries work fine until I try the COUNT function and then I get errors when trying to populate my JTable. The query works fine to populate a JTextArea so I know the query is ok.
My code is below any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import java.sql.*;
    import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class table {
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public table(){
        connect();
    }
    public void connect(){

        JTable tbl = new JTable();
        tbl.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
        JFrame resFrame = new JFrame("Results");
        resFrame.setLayout(null);
        resFrame.setSize(525, 445);
        resFrame.setVisible(true);
        JScrollPane tsp = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        tsp.setLocation(20, 20);
        resFrame.add(tsp);
        tbl.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        tsp.setSize(370,375);

        String sql = "SELECT Club, COUNT('memberID') AS total FROM Members_Table, Club_Table WHERE Club_Table.clubID=Members_Table.clubID GROUP BY Club";

        try{

            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            String db = "jdbc:odbc:ITUKdb";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            tbl.setModel(net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is below

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3906)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getObject(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1677)
    at net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(DbUtils.java:28)
    at trial.table.connect(table.java:53)
    at trial.table.<init>(table.java:22)
    at trial.ITUKSQL.main(ITUKSQL.java:212)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question and add the following details: 1. The error stack trace 2. The relevant section of the code or preferably an SSCCE version of your code. This will help us better analyze your question and point you to the right directions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted had to remove

```
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
```

From

```
 st = con.createStatement();
```